# How do I Remove these "Manual Column Break" Indicators from an MS Word File?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, indicator

In some .doc file generated online from a .pdf file using pdf to word converter, I see some "Manual Column Break" indicators in blue color as shown below.

[image]

This indicator appears a number of times in the .doc file. These were not present in the original .pdf file.

I have tried hard to remove these indicators without any success. This is what I have tried so far,

1. Naturally, I tried to select the indicator texts and delete them, these are not selectable.
2. I tried stopping view non printing characters, (Ctrl-F10 or [image] button, no success.
3. I tried un-checking, each and every item from View menu, again without success.

Could you please suggest a way how to remove these indicators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some findings,

1. These do not appear in the print preview, hence do not appear in any generated pdf file or hard copy print.
2. The markings *can not* be turned off. The only way out is to go to options and change "Page and Column break" color from "automatic" to "white". But be advised that this does not mean that they disappear or these are colorless. So, if the markings overlap some actual text, those texts will have a somewhat worm-eaten appearance.

The above knowledge was partially found at [this discussion](http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=59763).